# Inherited Template Variables Encapsulation

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

Ok, coming from a magento background, blocks have a template and a class tied to each one. This opens up specific methods to be acted upon from other areas of your application.

A simple example of this would be the head block.
from any location within the application you can get the head block and call the method setTitle to set the page title.

I'm understanding inheritance within symfony but I can't quite put my finger on setting up the business logic that should be attached to each block.

Could someone explain how I might include a head block and then from for example set the title variable that is shown on that template from a controller.

Comment: Give us an example in Magento then we can probably help you

Comment: Create a controller
Within the action:
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('my title tag value');
Is that a good example or do you want more?